# Best Practice to write a class in python that uses several models

Tags: python, class

I am writing the following code:

```
class Model_1:
   def __init__(self,some parameters):

   def simulate(self,steps,Number of simulation):
       ....
       return array
```

```
class Model_2:
   def __init__(self,some other parameters):

   def simulate(self,steps,Number of simulation):
       ....
       return array
```

```
class Object:
   def __init__(self,some other parameters):

   def get_price(self,Model, some other parameters):
       array = Model(parameters).simulate(parameters)
       array = array + do some stuff on array
       return array
```

My code is made up of several Models (so not only Model_1 and 2) and they all have a function `simulate(self,steps,Number of simulation)` that returns an array. Now depending on the model, the simulation isn't the same and I am not sure the best practice to write this line `array = Model_number.simulate(parameters)` in the code snippet above. What would be your best recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of the `Model` and send it as a parameter to `get_price`. I would also suggest using base class to handle all the commons between the `Model`s

```
class Model(ABC):
    def __init__(self, *some_parameters):
        self.some_parameters = some_parameters
        # now all the Models can access some_parameters tuple with self.some_parameters

    @abstractmethod
    def simulate(self, steps, number_of_simulation):
        pass


class Model1(Model):
    def __init__(self, *some_parameters):
        super().__init__(*some_parameters)

    def simulate(self, steps, number_of_simulation):
        array = []
        return array


class Model2(Model):
    def __init__(self, *some_parameters):
        super().__init__(*some_parameters)

    def simulate(self, steps, number_of_simulation):
        array = []
        return array


class Object:
    def __init__(self, some_other_parameters):
        pass

    def get_price(self, model, steps, number_of_simulation):
        array = model.simulate(steps, number_of_simulation)
        return array
```

Uses:

```
model1 = Model1(1, 2, 3)
model2 = Model2('asd', 'qwe')
model3 = Model2('zxc')

ob = Object(['some_other_parameters'])
ob.get_price(model1, 1, 1)
ob.get_price(model2, 2, 5)
ob.get_price(model3, 3, 7)
```